# Is there a shortcut in Eclipse to Re-run the most recently launched program?

Tags: eclipse, ide

One of the most frequent thing I do with Eclipse is to re-run the last program. I do it by going to *Run -> Run History -> [top most item]*.

Is there a shortcut key that does this?

I know of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> but this does not work for me. It will launch the most recent program only if the currently active class (the class whose source code I am editing) does not have a main method. If it does it will use this class as the entry point for the program and not the one from the Run History list.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

For <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to work the way you want, you must set (from "Windows/Preferences") the
"`Run/debug > Launching : Launch Operation`" setting to:

> Always launch the previously launched application

---

As  [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen) mentions in the comment, launching the last app used to be (3.2 or before) the default behavior.
Since [3.3M6](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/jdt-debug-home/New%20and%20Noteworthy/3.3/M6/whats-new-template.html?revision=1.4&content-type=text%2Fplain) (March 2007), As illustrated by [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg64996.html):

> By default, running and debugging applications has been simplified to run or debug the selected file or active editor.
>   When the selected resource (or active editor) is not executable, users can opt to launch the associated project or re-launch the previous launch.
>
> These settings are managed on the `Run/Debug > Launching` preference page.
>   Users can also revert to the 3.2 behavior of always launching the previous application.

---

[Torsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103412/torsten) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151995/is-there-a-shortcut-in-eclipse-to-re-run-the-most-recently-launched-program/1152039#comment81658551_1152039):

> Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> only launches the last application in debug mode.

Comment: This is actually the historic behaviour of Ctrl-F11.  Shame on those who changed.

Comment: The new behaviour is optimal for beginners that write a single executable class. The old approach is optimal for large tasks with multiple projects that may have several entry points.

Comment: Thanks, and for mac user it's Command+F11 (often the function buttons are not enabled by default so this is essentially Command+fn+F11)

Comment: If you need both behaviors, assign a simple key for launching current program, currently launched by alt+shift+x+ combination. For Java, I set Alt+j (assigned to join lines by default)

Comment: This seems to only launch run and not debug, is that the case for you? Can F11 for debug be configured similarly?

Comment: @Noumenon 8 years later, not too sure. I remember it should launch the last operation. So if the last session was a debug one, it should re-launch a debug session.

Comment: @VonC No need for doubts: Pressing F11 only launches the last application in debug mode. If you have the settings above, it behaves similarly as ctrl + F11.

Comment: @Torsten Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility

Answer (score 18):

*Run -> Run History -> [top most item]* is just <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. But downside of this way is that `Run` menu must contain only one item with 'T' hot-key.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, this does not solve my problem. See my edit above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For Scala projects (Scala IDE) I had to also add this to avoid selecting a Scala lanucher every time:

- **Run/Debug** > **Launching** > **Default Launchers preference**
- in **Launch Type/Mode** select **Scala Application**
- in **Preferred Launcher** select **Scala Application (new debugger) Launcher**

This also works for other launches that open a dialog when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> stands for `Relaunch with the same configuration.`

This works out for me!

At least in Pydev-Editor. I'm not sure about the other perspectives...

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-F11

And also you don't need to go to Run --> Run History. You can just click the small down arrow button next to the Run button (This looks like a green circle with a white play symbol in it) on your toolbar.

Comment: Yes, but when you're in the zone, keyboard works faster than a mouse

Comment: Exactly. Set the CTRL-F11 properly.

Comment: I am currently editing my JUnit test and I only want to run the test method I am writing. I do that by highlighting the method name first -> I do this every I time I want to run. So I googled for a shortcut for running the most recent run. I think this is a proper case where we need a separate shortcut for the most recent run

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **Ctrl + F11** works in Windows and **command + fn + F11** in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Ctl + F11 did not work for me either (Neon on Lubuntu). I started doing this:
`Alt + r + t + 1`

One could also use h instead of t to debug: `Alt + r + h + #`

I know it's a little longer but as long as I do not have to reach for the mouse and I can do it reliably on any Linux machine I am fine. Also, this way I can execute up to 9 previous runs by changing the number

Answer (score 0):

**Way One:**

Click the project from of this icon at this time hold the shift Button, Project will restart (Terminate and relaunch) with server port also.

[image]

**Way Two:**

[image]:

From of Eclipse Menu Bar:
Windows => Preferences => Type and select keys
type filter tex: terminate and relaunch
Bind your Shortcut Key Like this: