# Hot Key for Eclipse 'Run As'

Tags: eclipse

Has anyone mapped out a way to create a hot-key for 'Run As' in Eclipse (Used for running/launching a class/app)?

It would make life just that much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly "Run as...", but there's a hot key for each of the usual run configurations. For example, in windows:

```
Run Ant Build            Shift+Alt+X Q
Run Eclipse Application  Shift+Alt+X E
Run JUnit Plug-in Test   Shift+Alt+X P
Run JUnit Test           Shift+Alt+X T
Run Java Applet          Shift+Alt+X A
Run Java Application     Shift+Alt+X J
Run Last Launched        Ctrl+F11
Run SWT Application      Shift+Alt+X S
```

Comment: @Andaero not by default, but you can bind a new key combination for that. Take a look at this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430710/add-application-launch-shortcut-in-eclipse) for further instructions.