# Hide "Run on Server" Feature in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I never use "Run As -> Run on Server" in Eclipse. How do I hide it?

Comment: download Eclipse source, remove it and recompile. it's worth the effort, without that menu Eclipse is much better.

Comment: @abalogh there is a easier solution rather than to _download Eclipse source, remove it and recompile_ . So it's not worth the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Create your plug-in, then define your activities pattern to hide the context menus. Then export your plug-in into your eclipse, restart eclipse.

See [this blog post](http://kane-mx.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-rid-of-menus-of-eclipse-platform.html) how to find the id of context menu and use activities extension.

Answer (score 1):

**Straight forward easy 2 sec solution:**

- Run it once with that option, and if it's not meant to run on a server, then you'll get a pop up like the below saying 'The selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server.' 
  [image: run-on-server-pop-up-eclipse]
- Click ok.
- Now when you go to file --> right click, you'll not see that option anymore.

So the easiest solution to remove it is to run it with that option once.

I have also been frustrated with this and wanted to remove that option. I came looking for a viable/comfortable/doable answer, but couldn't find it. After months, i have found a easier solution for this. It's pretty straight forward as given above.

Comment: didn't work for me.  It actually ran on the server and I didn't get any error.  But I don't want it on the server. I'm using Tomcat so i want run as application.

Comment: actually this is what worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151995/is-there-a-shortcut-in-eclipse-to-re-run-the-most-recently-launched-program

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove server features and plugins. Cant find any setting/preference interface on eclipse? Right. Try this, it worked on my setup;

- Go to .../Eclipse-xxx/features/, find the folders starting with **org.eclipse.wst.server...**
- Create a new folder named "server-stuff" in in the folder "features"
- Move **org.eclipse.wst.server....** to **"server-stuff"** folder
- Go to .../Eclipse-xxx/plugins/, find the jar files starting with **org.eclipse.wst.server...**
- Create a new folder named "server-stuff" in the folder "plugins"
- Move **org.eclipse.wst.server...** to "server-stuff"

Now restart eclipse. All the damn "server" features gone.
If you encounter any unexpected result, just back-up with "server-stuff" folders.