# How to make the "run" button automatically launch the project with specified configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

With an open scala project, having open a random file, the run button looks like this:

[image]

Which outcomes like this:

[image]

But I want it to launch my specified launch configuration which only shows if the little arrow beneath the launch button is pressed:

[image]

How do I setup the launch button to launch with my specified configuration?

Comment: This might help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151995/is-there-a-shortcut-in-eclipse-to-re-run-the-most-recently-launched-program

Comment: Setting `Run/Debug > Launching -> Launch Operation > Always launch the previously launched application` was exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case one may stumble upon the same question, the solution is setting (in the settings window) `Run/Debug > Launching -> Launch Operation` to `Always launch the previously launched application`.