# eclipse c++ unit test shortcut

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Kepler CDT with Google Test. Unit testing is working fine, but **I can't find a way to get a shortcut to run all unit testing**. Everytime I need to run test, I have to click the little arrow near the *run* button and select the *unit test* icon.

I can't find c++ unit test in the "Keys" menu (although *Run JUnit test* is available).

Answer (score 0):

Still you can use Ctrl+F11 to launch the last Run Configuration, so launch once your tests by clicking, and then hit Ctrl+F11.

Comment: I tried, but CTRL+F11 launches the run configuration but the C++ Unit plugin isn't used.

Comment: You're right, for me it works randomly, sometimes picks the plugin, and sometimes not :-(

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+F11 to work the way you want, you must set (from "Windows/Preferences") the
"Run/debug > Launching : Launch Operation" setting to:

Answer in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152039