# Eclipse: How to make 'Run as' use the last used launcher

Tags: java, eclipse, launcher, run-configuration

Is there a way to make 'Run as' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>) run the active file, but with the most recently used launcher (such as Java Application, JUnit).

I have had this problem both with JUnit and Pitclipse, that whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to run, or press the 'Run as' button, it tries to run it as a JUnit or Pitclipse test no matter what I ran it as last time. I wish that if I run a file as a Java Application, the next file I run will by default also be ran as that.

It gets extremely annoying having to choose what to run as every time, or to change the keyboard shortcuts. I have checked all Launcher options, nothing seems to work.

Comment: It sounds like this is a duplicate question, but I'm not sure. Is your question the same as the question "Is there a shortcut in Eclipse to launch to Re-run the most recently launched program?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151995

Comment: @JonathanThoms unfortunately it is not. I do want to launch the currently selected program, not the most recently launched. However, I want it to use the same launcher as the most recently launched program (Java Application, JUnit, Debug etc).