# Eclipse - bind a specific program (launch configuration) to a hotkey

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing two apps simultaneously and I need to relaunch them often.

I read some things, that Eclipse provides 'launch last configuration' or 'launch most used configuration' but I couldn't find anything about binding certain apps to hotkeys.

I need to make it like:

- F10 - app1 launches
- F11 - app2 launches

.

Is there any addon or a way to achieve the goal?
Thanks!

Comment: You might check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151995/is-there-a-shortcut-in-eclipse-to-re-run-the-most-recently-launched-program). Best of luck!

Comment: you could try automating the clicks you make to run it..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437323/assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-specific-eclipse-build-configuration and this https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner#group-details

Comment: You can add your applications in Organize Run Favorites. After that, just press Alt -> R -> T -> 1 (1 is your first favorite application). Similarly, you can do for multiple applications.

Comment: You make parent app. after your apps put in the parent app and your parent app build two apps launcher.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926894/shortcut-for-selecting-run-configuration-in-eclipse-ide   
Try this its easy too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortcut for selecting run configuration in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926894/shortcut-for-selecting-run-configuration-in-eclipse-ide)